# Is it okay to ask a question a second time if it was not answered the first time?

Tags: discussion

Directly after a question is asked, it is shown to many people on the main page. However, if a question does not immediately receive an answer, it becomes dated and less people will see it. It thus often happens that dated questions do never receive proper answers. Especially if the question is asked at a time where less people are online.

Is it thus okay to simply ask the question again, say a week later, to have the chance that more people view it?

Comment: No, reasking is frowned upon. The question drifting off the front page is no concern. Users mostly follow *tags* they are interested in, and unanswered questions in favorite tags get enough attention.

Comment: You can edit your question a bit. Say, summarizing/adding your own new thoughts/approaches you tried but failed. Such an edit will "bump" your question to the front page of active question much the same way that reasking would (so reasking would only serve to make the site more difficult to search by creating an orphaned thread). Therefore: Watch out! Excessive bumping by editing is also frowned upon (because it pushes other questions off the front page).

Comment: Alright, thank you @JyrkiLahtonen. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: To prevent from all these duplicate questions arising from asking questions again and again (or at least a second time) if not answered the first time, we have **bounties**. However, if that doesn’t work, then it is the community’s job to put abandoned questions up on the homepage. (That last sentence, I read in the moderator’s bio.)

Comment: Alright, good to mention bounties and the job of the community. If all the comments could be written up as answer, that would probably answer the question.

Comment: Why do you dislike the question? I asked in order not to make a mistake. And I even agreed with all comments... can't believe it. Would you like it more if I just went ahead next time?